# i nedd save information into database when turn of browser

Tags: php, javascript, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

I need to save the current time into database when shutting down the browser.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

thanks

Comment: You'll want to send an AJAX request to the server in the `onbeforeunload` event and record it there. Millions of dupes on Stack Overflow, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584288/can-the-unload-event-be-used-to-reliably-fire-ajax-request, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350900/sending-a-request-back-to-server-in-onbeforeunload-event or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821625/ajax-request-with-jquery-on-page-unload for starters.

Answer (score 0):

the unload event maybe work.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  //write the time to database
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onunload = function() {

var time = new Date().getTime();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "index.php?closetime="+time, true);
xhr.send();

};
```

In index.php use $_GET["closetime"] and save it to database.

Answer (score -1):

You can listen for the `onbeforeunload` event.  You can make a call to the database when this event fires.  Check out [this article](http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/) to learn how you might use this in a cross-browser fashion.

Comment: "Making a call to the database" when the `onbeforeunload` event fires (assuming you're expecting him to use AJAX) is easier said than done.