# PUT on Tab Close Doesn't Complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, oboe.js

On close of a browser tab, I'm attempting to do an automatic save of the user's changes. I have verified this works at other points in the timeline; the same function is used. I call it in the `unload` handler:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {        
    saveAnnotations(pdfState.pdfs[pdfState.activePdfIndex].PdfPages[pdfState.activePageIndex]);
});
```

Saving the user's changes involves a RESTful PUT inside that `saveAnnotations` function, using the [Oboe](http://www.oboejs.com/) library:

```
oboe({
  url: configuration.rootApiUrl + 'PdfPages/' + page.ID,
  method: 'PUT',
  body: page
}).done(function(jobs) { // Our call does not provide a callback
  if(callback !== undefined && _.isFunction(callback)) {
    callback();
  }
});
```

The server receiving this is a Microsoft Web API server. I'm running both the client and the server locally for testing.

In diagnosing this I edited the above code in place to be a GET rather than a PUT, and it hit a breakpoint inside the route on the server. However, when doing a PUT, I do not hit the breakpoint inside that server route on tab close. Why would it work for a GET and not a PUT? What must I do so that the server can receive my PUT? My hunch is that it is client side, not server side. If it would be helpful to see the server route I can post that, but otherwise I don't want to clutter the question.

Comment: the unload event is different from other events.  It is meant to prompt the user with a message, not fire an ajax call.  But you can try a few things I guess.  Oh look, here is a link that was the first result when typing your question into google.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584288/can-the-unload-event-be-used-to-reliably-fire-ajax-request

Comment: @QBM5 What is the correct event to listen on then? The linked question doesn't seem to provide that information.

Comment: You can **never** do this reliably. Better to just autosave every X minutes, or every X changes that a user has done.

Comment: As I said.  When the user closer the tab that's it.  There is no way to reliably send an Ajax call on any event related to a close