# Call ajax on before page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call an ajax  before user leaving a page, this what i have done so far. But it doesn't even hit the ajax page.
This is what i have done so far.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt();
function closeIt()
{
    var key="save-draft";

            $.ajax({
                url: "app/ajax_handler.php",
                type:"GET",
                data:{key:key},
                success: function(data)  {
                    return data;
                }
            });

}
```

I Have tried this one also both failed in my case.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {});
```

Comment: That request is wiped out because page is gone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596222/2270492

Comment: so you are saying actually it is worked or not?

Comment: If server is fast, server process will be executed for sure but you cant confirm it on client

Comment: actually iam sending a imap request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794301/window-onunload-is-not-working-properly-in-chrome-browser-can-any-one-help-me

Comment: is there any way to delay the next page loading even if it is working?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think is to let the user know that it's a process on background with a confirm message, that will block the exit until user click on Accept or you've got the response.

Something like that:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt();
function closeIt()
{
    /*var key="save-draft";

            $.ajax({
                url: "app/ajax_handler.php",
                type:"GET",
                data:{key:key},
                success: function(data)  {
                    return data;
                }
            });*/
  
      setTimeout(function() {
                                return confirm("There is a process that isn't finished yet, you will lose some data. Are you sure you want to exit?");
                        }, 1000);

}
```